# Difference of the "Browser." and "Messenger." when using a webextension/javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, thunderbird-webextensions

Good day, I am new to using webextension and javascript apis. Just wondering what is the difference of using messsenger.(API) and Browser.(API)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but my understanding is that the following: Both `browser` and `messenger` are namespaces that can be used to call WebExtension API in Thunderbird. I suppose that `browser` exists because it was inherited from Firefox, from which Thunderbird gets some of the code for WebExtensions (they have many APIs in common). But Thunderbird is not meant to be a browser, above all it's an email client. So I suppose the `messenger` namespace was added to reflect that.

This seems to be corroborated by the [documentation for the MailExtensions API](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/78/)

> In Thunderbird, all WebExtension API can be accessed through the *browser.** namespace, as with Firefox, but also through the *messenger.** namespace, which is a better fit for Thunderbird.

I would see it pretty much as the same thing as *WebExtensions* being called indifferently *WebExtensions* or *MailExtensions* for Thunderbird.

Assuming my hypothesis is correct, there should be no practical difference in using one over the other.